# Creating 2 object instead of 1

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

There is one button in the game and if you click him, the button needs to create an object, but when you click it first, it's creating one clone, but after you clicked the second time it's creating adding one more clone to other instead of one clone.

```
public float positionX;
public float positionY;
public Button buttonUp;
Button btn1;
```

First, I created the variables.

```
void Start () 
{
    positionX = transform.position.x;
    positionY = transform.position.y;

    btn1 = buttonUp.GetComponent<Button>();
}
```

Then assigned the position's values on Start Method and Button component

```
void Update() 
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        btn1.onClick.AddListener(UpClicked);
    }
}
```

And controlled if a user clicks button set addListener

```
float[] CreatePlayerPartsUp(float pX, float pY)
{
    float positionXFun = pX;
    float positionYFun = pY;

    GameObject part = Instantiate(playerParts, new Vector2(positionXFun, positionYFun + 16), Quaternion.identity);

    float[] turnPosition = new float[2]{part.transform.position.x, part.transform.position.y};

    return turnPosition;
}
```

After, I created a method that keeps the position of the object and returned them by using an array.

```
void UpClicked()
{
    float[] createdPosition= CreatePlayerPartsUp(positionX, positionY);
    positionX = createdPosition[0];
    positionY = createdPosition[1];
}
```

Finally, I called the method and assigned the new position.

But the problem has occurred and I don't know why it happened. (First, create 1 but the other times it starts to create adding one more clone to other instead of 1)

Comment: I'm a little unclear what you mean by "but after you clicked the second time it's creating adding one more clone to other instead of one clone". Could you expand a bit? Also, if you click a third time, do you get three clones?

Comment: It keeps creating one more clone of the created clones. e.g if you click 3 times it creates 3 objects instead of one object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem is happening because you're adding a button click listener each time the mouse is clicked (in your `Update` function).  The first time the mouse is clicked it adds the first listener during the `Update`, the 2nd time the mouse is clicked it adds another listener during the `Update`.  So now when the mouse is clicked both of these listeners are triggered, adding 2 objects instead of 1.  This pattern would repeat, i.e. clicking a 3rd time would cause it to add 3 objects now.

Move the `AddListener` function call into your `Start` function so that there is only one listener added, like so:

```
void Start () 
{
    positionX = transform.position.x;
    positionY = transform.position.y;

    btn1 = buttonUp.GetComponent<Button>();
    btn1.onClick.AddListener(UpClicked);
}

void Update() 
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The culprit is in your Update() Method:

```
void Update() 
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        btn1.onClick.AddListener(UpClicked);
    }
}
```

This adds another call to `UpClickd()` to the `onClick` event each time the mouse is clicked, which is probably not what you wanted.

Move the `AddListener` to the Start() function - so there is only one function call when the event occurs.